# Using Openlayers 3 highlight or add style to WMS layer with map click

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, style

I followed this solution. But I am unable to highlight the feature. Can anyone help what is wrong....!!

```
var style1 = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ff6600',
        width: 4
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});
var styles1 = [style1];
var SearchtalukLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    id: 'Highlight',
    style: function (feature, resolution) {
        style1.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('') : '');
        return styles1;
    }
});
var tank = new ol.layer.Image({
    id: "tank",
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.136:8092/geoserver/fisherier/wms',
        type: 'feature',
        params: {
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'VERSION': '1.1.0',
            'LAYERS': 'fisherier:karnatakawatertankfinal'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    }),
});
//======================================================================
var map = new ol.Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
    tank,SearchtalukLayer
],
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([77, 15]),
    zoom: 7 
})
});
var styleClick = function(feature, resolution) {
return [
    new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [245, 121, 0, 0.8] }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: [0,0,0,1] }),
            radius: 7
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '24px Verdana',
            offsetY: 20,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: [255, 255, 255, 0.8]
            })
        })
     })
  ];
};
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: styleClick
});
map.addInteraction(select);
var layerlist = [tank]; 
map.on('click', function(evt){
  console.info(evt.pixel);
  console.info(map.getPixelFromCoordinate(evt.coordinate))      
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var urldist = tank.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
        {
            'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/javascript',
            'propertyName': ['districtna', 'talukname', 'villagenam', 'tank_nic', 'objectid', 'districtco']
        });

    if (urldist) {
        var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        $.ajax({
            url: urldist,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
        }).then(function (response) {
            var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
            if (result.length) {
                var info = [];
                var distictname,talukname,tank_id;
                for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
                    obj_id = result[i].get('objectid');
                    distictname = result[i].get('districtna');
                    talukname = result[i].get('talukname');
                    villagename = result[i].get('villagenam');
                    tank_id = result[i].get('tank_nic');
                    distictcode = result[i].get('districtco');
                }
                var testobj = obj_id.toString();
                alert(testobj);     
                tankhighlight(testobj, SearchtalukLayer);              
            }
        });
    }   
});
function tankhighlight(testobj, SearchtalukLayer) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.136:8092/geoserver/fisherier/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=fisherier:vwtesttankhighl&maxFeatures=5000&outputFormat=text/javascript',   
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: "parseResponse",
        data: {
            viewparams: "objectid: " + testobj
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert("122 " + testobj);
            SearchtalukLayer.setSource(null);
            var searchresultssource = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response, {
                    dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", //need to Change
                    featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
                })
            });
            SearchtalukLayer.setSource(searchresultssource);
            console.log(searchresultssource)
            map.getView().fit(SearchtalukLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());

        }

    });   
}
```

Comment: There's way too much code in your question, in general you should just add enough code to reproduce the problem.   Your title mentions WMS, but your code uses WMS and WFS.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone help what is wrong

Your title says you want to *highlight or add style to **WMS layer** with map click*, and the body says that you are *unable to highlight **the feature**.*

So the obvious thing here is that **there are no features in the map** to highlight, because a WMS doesn't return features it returns map images.  A WMS allows you to query features in the data that created the map by using a GetFeatureInfo request.

If the WMS is SLD enabled, then you can change the styling in the map by sending a GetMap request with your style added.

Comment: The control will goes to highlight function and selected object id also displayed in array but it doesn't highlight the selected feature can you please suggest me some examples to highlight the feature ...thank u

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/229894/edit) the question to add more detail.  You should perhaps explain your logic then give ta bit of code, then logic then code. etc.  You mention WMS in the title but you include WFS code how does this fit in (or how do you see it working)? For example you have a WMS layer or layers (an image~ not features), you click on the map to get some information (a GetFeatureInfo request), and from the information returned you want what to happen?